# stopping duplicate values in search result

Tags: php

this is my search result. as you see, there is repetitive rasults. it is true but its not too beautiful to have one name serval times.

[image]

> code:

```
<?php

   $db_host = 'localhost';
   $db_name= 'site';
   $db_table= 'tablesite';
   $db_user = 'root';
   $db_pass = '';



   $con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("خطا در اتصال به پايگاه داده");
$selected=mysql_select_db($db_name, $con) or die("خطا در انتخاب پايگاه داده");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET  utf8");
$dbresult=mysql_query("SELECT tablesite.name,
                              tablesite.family,
                              tablesite.phone_number,
                              job_list.job_name,
                              relation.comments,
SUM(CASE WHEN action.vote !='' AND action.customer_comment ='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) positive,
SUM(CASE WHEN action.vote !='' AND action.customer_comment !='' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) negative

                       FROM tablesite
                       INNER JOIN relation
                       on tablesite.id_user=relation.user_id
                       INNER JOIN job_list
                       on relation.job_id=job_list.job_id 

                       left JOIN action
                       ON tablesite.id_user=action.service_provider_id
                       WHERE job_name LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'
                               OR name LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'
                               OR family LIKE '%".$_POST['search']."%'
                       group by name,family,job_name,phone_number",$con);
?>
   <title>نتایج جستجو</title><fieldset class="fdex"  dir="rtl">
    <legend><span class="style4">نتایج جستجوی مشاغل</span></legend>

   <?php

   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($dbresult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

   printf("نام: %s   %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
           شغل: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
           شماره تلفن: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
           عملیات های موفق: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
           عملیات نا موفق: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
           توضیحات: %s<br>",
           $row["name"],
           $row["family"],
           $row["job_name"], 
           $row["phone_number"], 
           $row["positive"], 
           $row["negative"], 
           $row["comments"]);

}
?>
</fieldset>
```

it should be like this:

[image]

i want to echo name,family just one time when name,family are more than one time

this style is user friendly and have a good viewing. thank you all...

Comment: set limit in query http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp

Comment: i dont want to limit records!!!!! i want to echo name,family just one time when name,family printed more than one time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$firstname = '';
$oldfirst = '';
$lastname = '';
$oldlast = '';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($dbresult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    if($oldfirst == $row['name'] && $oldlast == $row['family'])
    {
        $firstname = ' ';
        $lastname = ' ';
        $namelabel = ' ';
    }
    else
    {
        $firstname = $row['name'];
        $lastname = $row['family'];
        $namelabel = 'نام: ';
    }

    $oldfirst = $row['name'];
    $oldlast = $row['family'];

    printf("{$namelabel} %s   %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        شغل: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        شماره تلفن: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        عملیات های موفق: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        عملیات نا موفق: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        توضیحات: %s<br>",
        $firstname,
        $lastname,
        $row["job_name"], 
        $row["phone_number"], 
        $row["positive"], 
        $row["negative"], 
        $row["comments"]);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Although I recomment not to use printf. Use tables instead.

Comment: it is mostly true but please limit name and family together and also remove "نام" field where there is not no name and family

Comment: @sajad jan how about it

Comment: :) Well it's actually simple. Each time you store name and family values so that in the next iteration you can compare the new values with them. If both are matched, we empty the values to be printed, if not, then we print the new values. نام field is also handled inside the if conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It will solve your problem.

```
 $temp_array = array();
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($dbresult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
     if(in_array($row["name"], $temp_array))
        $row["name"] = '';
     else
        array_push($temp_array, $row["name"]); 

   printf("نام: %s   %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
           شغل: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
           شماره تلفن: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
           عملیات های موفق: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
           عملیات نا موفق: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
           توضیحات: %s<br>",
           $row["name"],
           $row["family"],
           $row["job_name"], 
           $row["phone_number"], 
           $row["positive"], 
           $row["negative"], 
           $row["comments"]);

}
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: temp_array in C:\wamp\www\source\searchresults_simple.php on line 56

Comment: and Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in C:\wamp\www\source\searchresults_simple.php on line 56 --> line 56: if(in_array($row["name"], $temp_array))

Comment: I have updated the answer. Now try. It will work fine

Comment: no! Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in C:\wamp\www\source\searchresults_simple.php on line 58. you have not removed name and family you just removed name. also when there is not name and family no need to "نام" prints

Comment: sinazza's code running property but prints family and "نام" even when there is not no name and family

Comment: I have updated the ans. There was a mistake in variable name. Now check

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with *$name alone* since it is getting repeated.Add  this code and run  you will get your expected output

```
<?php
$oldname="";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($dbresult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$newname=$row["name"];
if($newname!=$oldname)
printf("نام: %s   %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
       شغل: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
       شماره تلفن: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
       عملیات های موفق: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
       عملیات نا موفق: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
       توضیحات: %s<br>",
       $newname,
       $row["family"],
       $row["job_name"], 
       $row["phone_number"], 
       $row["positive"], 
       $row["negative"], 
       $row["comments"]);
$oldname=$newname;
}
else{
printf("نام: %s   %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
       شغل: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
       شماره تلفن: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
       عملیات های موفق: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
       عملیات نا موفق: %s &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
       توضیحات: %s<br>",
       ,//empty name
       $row["family"],
       $row["job_name"], 
       $row["phone_number"], 
       $row["positive"], 
       $row["negative"], 
       $row["comments"]);
 $oldname=$newname;
}
?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: name in C:\wamp\www\source\searchresults_simple.php on line 65 -->this line: $name,